# Count Occurence in 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays

I have this 2d array

```
**Client| Status** 

    FAI | deferred
    SDE | Bounced
    FAI | Bounced
    SDE | Bounced
    SDE | deferred
    FAI | deferred
```

What i want to do i s to create a function, that make some kind of statistical output:
EX:

```
FAI --> Deferred 66 % , Bounced 34 %
SDE --> Deferred 34 % , Bounced 66%
```

N.B. 
For the first column there is a lot of possible clients, but for the second i have only those two states.

The function that i want to create is a function that count the occurrence of the first column elements, then for each client see the state in each occurrence if it is Bounced or referred, an d make a statistics for the client.

Here i don't really how to start my function,So any idea, any suggestion is welcome, and will help me.
Thank you!

Comment: all good but where is the code you have tried?

Comment: Whack it into a `Map<String, List<String>>` or a Guava `Multimap` and then calculate the percentages.

Comment: It would help if you described the data structure that you use to keep this data. One possible idea is to use something like Map<String, List<Integer>>, using as key the client name and a list with two Integers one for "bounced" and one for "deferred".

Comment: I will use Map<String, Map<String, int>>: the outer map for the clientes and the inner map for the count of Deferred or Bounced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HashMap(or any other implementation of Map interface) to efficient solve your problem(@kai  solution is ok, but it is O(N^2)). This example is not generic, it only works if in second column of grid(data matrix) you have two possible values(deffered and bounced). Solution works in this way: we iterate over rows in data matrix and check if current entity(represent by name - first column of grid) is already in hashmap. If it is, just increment that entity percents(inc method of Entity class), otherwise we must first create new instance of entity, add it to hashmap and than increment percents. Printing is done similar(because we need to print names in same order they appear in matrix): we iterate again over data and print entity object(this is why toString method is overridden). isVisitedMember attr in Entity class is used because we want to print every entity just once.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HelloWorld{
 static class Entity {
    private String name;
    private int countFirst;
    private int countSecond;
    private boolean isVisitedMember; // because we want to print in same order as in original matrix

    public Entity(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        countFirst = 0;
        countSecond = 0;
        isVisitedMember = false;
    }

    public void inc(String status) {
        if (status.toLowerCase().equals("deferred")) {
            ++countFirst;
        }
        else {
            ++countSecond;   
        }
    }

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return isVisitedMember;
    }

    public void setIsVisited(boolean value) {
        isVisitedMember = value;
    }

    public float getFirstPercent() {
        return (float)countFirst / (countFirst + countSecond) * 100;
    }

    public float getSecondPercent() {
        return (float)countSecond / (countFirst + countSecond) * 100;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (countFirst <= countSecond) {
            int first = (int)Math.ceil(getFirstPercent());
            return String.format("%s --> Deferred %d %% , Bounced %d %%", name, first, 100 - first);
        }

        int second = (int)Math.ceil(getSecondPercent());
        return String.format("%s --> Deferred %d %% , Bounced %d %%", name, 100 - second, second);
    }
 }


 public static void main(String []args){
    String[][] data = {
        { "FAI", "deferred" },
        { "SDE", "Bounced" },
        { "FAI", "Bounced" },
        { "SDE", "Bounced" },
        { "SDE", "deferred" },
        { "FAI", "deferred" },
    };

    HashMap<String, Entity> map = new HashMap<String, Entity>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        String name = data[i][0];
        String value = data[i][1];
        Entity entity = map.get(name);
        if (entity == null) {
            entity = new HelloWorld.Entity(name);
            map.put(name, entity);
        }

        entity.inc(value);
    }

    // print in same order as in original matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        String name = data[i][0];
        Entity entity = map.get(name);
        if (entity.isVisited()) {
            continue;
        }

        entity.setIsVisited(true);
        System.out.println(entity);
    }        
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a List of all clients. Then you can count the number of deffered and bounced which every client have.
Here is my solution. Its not the best way to do this, but it works! The output is:

FAI --> Deffered 67 % , Bounced 33%

SDE --> Deffered 33 % , Bounced 67%

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

      String[][] client_status = new String[6][2];
      client_status[0][0] = "FAI";
      client_status[0][1] = "deffered";
      client_status[1][0] = "SDE";
      client_status[1][1] = "Bounced";
      client_status[2][0] = "FAI";
      client_status[2][1] = "Bounced";
      client_status[3][0] = "SDE";
      client_status[3][1] = "Bounced";
      client_status[4][0] = "SDE";
      client_status[4][1] = "deffered";
      client_status[5][0] = "FAI";
      client_status[5][1] = "deffered";


      List<String> clients = new ArrayList<String>();

      int allDeffered = 0;
      int allBounced = 0;

      for(int i = 0; i < client_status.length; i++) {
          if(!clients.contains(client_status[i][0])) {
              clients.add(client_status[i][0]);
          }  
      }

      Integer[] clientDeffered = new Integer[clients.size()];
      Integer[] clientBounced = new Integer[clients.size()];

      int k = 0;
      for(String client : clients) {
          for(int j = 0; j<client_status.length; j++) {
              if(client_status[j][0].equals(client)&&client_status[j][1].equals("deffered")) {
                  if(clientDeffered[k]==null) {
                      clientDeffered[k]=1;
                  }
                  else {
                      clientDeffered[k]++;
                  }
                  allDeffered ++;
              }
              if(client_status[j][0].equals(client)&&client_status[j][1].equals("Bounced")) {
                  if(clientBounced[k]==null) {
                      clientBounced[k]=1;
                  }
                  else {
                      clientBounced[k]++;
                  }
                  allBounced ++;

              }
          }
          k++;
      }
      for(int l = 0; l<clients.size(); l++) {
          double a = clientDeffered[l];
          double b = allDeffered;
          double c = clientBounced[l];
          double d = allBounced; 
          System.out.println(clients.get(l) +" --> Deffered " +Math.round((a/b)*100) + " % , Bounced " +Math.round((c/d)*100) + "%");
      }   
  }
```